# Oracle TIMEDATE to DATE

Tags: sql, eclipse, oracle, to-char, to-date

I am having trouble converting a datetime field into date. Here is the query:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(PROJ.RECEIVEDDATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
FROM PROJ
```

But when I run it I get the following error, "ORA-01843: not a valid month"

So I tried to convert to char first then to date

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PROJ.RECEIVEDDATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
FROM PROJ
```

But get the wrong output, "2005-01-18 00:00:00.0"

Comment: What do you see if you simply run the to_char function?

Comment: Formatting is correct when I do to_char but then it is not a date so it only sorts by numerical order.

Comment: If this is inside Eclipse, then you are using JDBC.  Its been a while but will `SELECT RECEIVEDDATE FROM PROJ` not return a java.sql.Date object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're a little confused about the `DATE` data type, as that has a time component - there isn't a separate `DATETIME` type in Oracle. If your `RECEIVEDDATE` field is already a `DATE`, as seems to be the case, then you're converting it unnecessarily, but you're also doing an implicit conversion to a string in the middle.

```
TO_DATE(PROJ.RECEIVEDDATE, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

is really doing

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PROJ.RECEIVEDDATE, <NLS_DATE_FORMAT>), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

... and the ORA-08143 error suggests you NLS format might be `DD/MM/YYYY`. When the day part of the date is greater than 12, you can expect that kind of error, since there is no month with a number greater than 12. It looks like you're working with 2005-01-18, so it's trying to interpret 18 as a month, so the error is reasonable.

From how you've phrased the first part of the question I think you're trying to strip the time portion of the field, which your second query is doing - that works since you have an explicit date format model this time. But doing two conversions isn't really necessary, you can use the [`TRUNC` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions220.htm) to do that:

```
SELECT TRUNC(PROJ.RECEIVEDDATE)
FROM PROJ
```

The final part is a bit confusing though - that isn't 'wrong', it's how you're client is choosing to format the `DATE` value. If you want to see it in a particular format, just use `TO_CHAR`, and then you don't even need the `TRUNC`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(PROJ.RECEIVEDDATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
FROM PROJ
```

... but it depends what you're doing - if you're using it purely for display that's fine, if it will be used elsewhere in a bigger query then leave it as a `DATE`.

Comment: The data for RECEIVEDDATE is return as  2005-01-18 22:35:31.0, I want it as MM/dd/yyyy but from everything I tried, nothing works

Comment: @user2953762 - your client seems to be formatting it like that You could try changing your client settings, but it would be better to just specify the format you want with `TO_CHAR`. But you implied you want to order by it, in which case you should leave it as a `DATE`. At lease for the `ORDER BY` clause.